# R changes my dataframe to values

Tags: r, gsub

```
head(merge1agg, n=10)
           geneWB  gene       sample       tpm
1  WBGene00000001 aap-1  1_EV_Con_3h 53.897797
2  WBGene00000001 aap-1  2_EV_Con_3h 55.815907
3  WBGene00000001 aap-1  3_EV_Con_3h 57.567861
4  WBGene00000001 aap-1 5_EV_NaCl_3h 58.090733
5  WBGene00000001 aap-1 6_EV_NaCl_3h 57.004453
6  WBGene00000001 aap-1 7_EV_NaCl_3h 59.762026
7  WBGene00000002 aat-1  1_EV_Con_3h  3.468561
8  WBGene00000002 aat-1  2_EV_Con_3h  3.692563
9  WBGene00000002 aat-1  3_EV_Con_3h  3.754730
10 WBGene00000002 aat-1 5_EV_NaCl_3h  4.800149
```

I'm trying to gsub with this command

```
test <- gsub("1_EV_Con_3h", "EV_Con_3h", merge1agg)
```

it seems to work, but 'test' ends up in 'values' and losses formatting that I had in 'merge1agg'.  How can I do this but keep the dataframe?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to replace the `sample` column in your dataframe? Do something like `merge1agg$sample = gsub("this","that",merge1agg$sample)`. Read a basic R intro for more basic R stuff like this.

Comment: I am very curious about such interesting changes. Please show and not tell us the output.

Comment: > head(test, n=10)
[1] "c(\"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000001\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000002\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000003\", \"WBGene00000004\", \"WBGene00000004\", \"WBGene00000004\", ## I cut it off here to fit.

Comment: It looks like it changes the dataframe to four different very long characters, one for each column in merge1agg.